# Javascript calendar with year select and time select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Do you know any javascript/jQuery or any other JS library calendar that allows the user to select the year but also the minutes???

jQuery timepicker addon by Trent Richardson would have been perfect but the user cannot change the year, just the month. I have to follow rigid specs on this one...

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/ - After 3 seconds of typing into google.

Comment: are you kidding me? thanks for the down vote, please read my question carefully first! And after that show me how on your datetimepicker suggestion the user can change the minutes!!! It can change only the hours!!!! (fyi i am goggling this for hours now!)

Comment: I have a stupid question for you: are you here to argue or to help? if you can't help on this topic please find another one. Thank you

Comment: The TimePicker add-on from Trent Richardson meets every requirement you mentioned. You just neglected to actually try and solve the problem yourself. View my answer below to see how to actually use the plugin how you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this plugin to unobtrusively add a datetimepicker, datepicker or timepicker dropdown to your forms. It's easy to customize options.

Refer this [link](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)

**Edit:**

```
  <input type="text" name="date6" value="">
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
         $('*[name=date6]').appendDtpicker({
         "inline": true,
         "minuteInterval": 15
         });
      });
  </script>
```

by the use of `minuteInterval` property you can set minutes interval.

For more information about this code this link will be help full to you.

**this llink for code :**

[jquery-simple-datetimepicker](https://github.com/mugifly/jquery-simple-datetimepicker/blob/master/jquery.simple-dtpicker.html)

**this link for Demo :**

[Demo - jquery-simple-datetimepicker](http://mugifly.github.io/jquery-simple-datetimepicker/jquery.simple-dtpicker.html)

I am not sure this code is true or not but it may help you.
I have refer this code from above links.

i hope this link will helpful to you.

Comment: I have marked your answer as accepted and up vote it. Thank you for helping me out. Inspired by your answer i have noticed that  the first link you posted (http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) has an option called "step" which can be used to change the interval between hours and minutes

Comment: it's my please that I could help especially for this question.

Comment: I also appreciate your question.

Answer (score 1):

The [Time Picker add-on by Trent Richardson](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) works correctly for you and meets all of your requirements specified, you just need to add the options that the jQuery DatePicker requires to enable the Year and Month to be selectable.

From the Options page of the Time-Picker add-on :

> The timepicker does inherit all options from datepicker.

Code :

```
$('#test').datetimepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

This will now create a Date-Time picker with the Year and Months as selectable dropdowns.

Comment: thank you so much! I have already accepted an answer before reading yours so i will just up vote :) This saves me the trouble to change the calendar and possibly a custom validator i built so is the best solution in my specific situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification on the JQuery UI TimePicker
http://puna.net.nz/timepicker.htm#

Comment: looks interesting but the year cannot be changed, just the month

Comment: Ok. You can move the months for year but I see you want the user to type in the year as well. This one is pretty good. I used it for one of my sites but later switched to the mod one http://www.ama3.com/anytime/